# Get my country's date and how to compare dates in php

Tags: php

I need to get my country's current date. Currently my project is getting the user's date.
Here are my questions:

1. how to get my country's current date?
2. If I'm running my php site in my localhost (wampp), will I still get my country's current date? (I have an internet connection by the way).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Please google: `time()`, `date()`, `date_default_timezone_set()` and take a look at this page: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Hi, currently I'm using the date() function. And now I'm testing the date_default_timezone_set().... It also returns a date BASED on my system. Whenever I change my pc's date to september, 2014 my script returns the same date on my system. I'm thinking, will it work if I host my php file on a free hosting site? will it return a correct date even if I change my pc's date?

Comment: PHP fetches time info from the server (your local system in this case). Then, with `date_default_timezone_set()` you can set any time zone you need; so you always get the same date/time information regardless of the server in which your code is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP fetches time info from the server (your local system in this case). Then, with `date_default_timezone_set()` you can set any time zone you need.

Please, try this simple code and see what happens:

```
America/Montreal:<br>
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("America/Montreal");
echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s", time());
?>

<br>

Asia/Aden: <br>
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Aden");
echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s", time());
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir. the function fetches the date/time in its current server. :)